# Function argument with a record destruct which is a single value union type, and alias

Tags: elm

I'm using a union type with a single value for my ID to be type safe:

```
type PositionIdType = PositionId Int
```

Let's say I have a record:

```
type alias Position =
    { id : PositionIdType
    , x : Float
    , y : Float
    }
```

I understand I can do a record destruct:

```
function : Position -> a
function { id } =
    -- id is a PositionIdType
```

and similarly via assignment:

```
{ id } = Position (PositionId 99) 10 5
```

If I need to access the record too:

```
function : Position -> a
function ({ id } as position) =
    -- id is a PositionIdType
    -- position is a Position
```

And also destructing a single type:

```
function : PositionIdType -> a
function (PositionId id) =
    -- id is an Int
```

Also via assignment:

```
(PositionId id) = (Position (PositionId 99) 10 5).id
```

Is it possible to join these two together? I have tried a few different ways without success, e.g.:

```
getIdInt ((PositionId { id }) as position) = id
getIdInt ({(PositionId id)} as position) = id
getIdInt (({PositionId id}) as position) = id
```

My current solution is to do it in a `let`/`in` block, which works just fine, but would be very nice to skip the let block if possible:

```
processPosition : Position -> a
processPosition ({id} as position) =
    let
        (PositionId id_) =
            id
    in
        Http.post ("/position/" ++ id_) (positionEncoder position)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (`0.18.0`), destruncturing of nested Union Type value inside of the Record is impossible.

There's no info if this feature will ever land.

Here is a reference of [record destructuring.](https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/4f563fbf81ff843e8b1e#record)

Tuple is the only Elm type, which allows nested destructuring.

```
nested ( x, ( y ) ) =  
  x + y

> nested ( 1, (1))
2 : number
```

Destructuring of Union Type is only possible with `if..else` expression, `case` expression or when it is passed directly as an argument to the function.

Here's what I would have done, if I were to write `getIdInt`:

```
getIdInt : Position -> Int
getIdInt { id } =
  case id of
    PositionId val ->
      val

main =
  Position (PositionId 99) 10 5
    |> getIdInt
    |> toString
    |> text -- 99
```